# Reflection on the Right Side of Image in Android ImageView

Tags: android, image, reflection, imageview, paint

I have an image and I want to give reflection to that image in Android application, below is the source code. I've found an example code

```
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);                
      imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);

    //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
      final int reflectionGap = 4;

      //Get you bit map from drawable folder
      Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
              imageIDs[position]);

      int width = originalImage.getWidth();
      int height = originalImage.getHeight();


      //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.preScale(1, -1);

      //Create a Bitmap with the flip matix applied to it.
      //We only want the bottom half of the image
      Bitmap reflectionImage ;
      if(isVertical)
          reflectionImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);
      else
          reflectionImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, width/2, 0, width/2, height, matrix, false);

      //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
      Bitmap bitmapWithReflection;
      if(isVertical)
          bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width 
        , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);
      else
          bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width +width/2
                    , height, Config.ARGB_8888);

     //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
     //the image plus gap plus reflection
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
     //Draw in the original image
     canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
     //Draw in the gap
     Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
     if(isVertical)
     canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
     else
         canvas.drawRect(width, 0, width+reflectionGap, height, deafaultPaint);
     //Draw in the reflection
     if(isVertical)
     canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);
     else
         canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,width + reflectionGap,0 , null);

     //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
     Paint paint = new Paint(); 
     LinearGradient shader;
     if(isVertical)
     shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0, 
       bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, 
       TileMode.CLAMP); 
     else
         shader = new LinearGradient(originalImage.getWidth(),0,  
                   bitmapWithReflection.getWidth() + reflectionGap,0,  0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff,
                   TileMode.CLAMP); 
     //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
     paint.setShader(shader); 
     //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
     paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
     //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
     if(isVertical)
     canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, 
       bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint); 
     else
         canvas.drawRect(width, 0, bitmapWithReflection.getWidth() + reflectionGap, 
                   height, paint); 

     //Create an Image view and add our bitmap with reflection to it
     //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);`
```

This example works gracefullt when I give isVertical value=true, ath the bottom of the image, but I want to use reflection effect at the right side of the image also because I think it will be better in landscape mode. But it does not work as I want. It shows reflection side top-bottom reversed. What is my mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix has to change:

```
if (isVertical) {
  matrix.preScale(1, -1);
  reflectionImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);
}
else {
  matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
  reflectionImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, width/2, 0, width/2, height, matrix, false);

}
```